# SFTP in the ForEach Activity

Tags: sql-server, foreach, azure-pipelines, sftp

A ForEach task performs a "data copy" from SQL DB to .txt file and with sftp service writes the files to a folder on the server. This is done 10 times. The files are all named differently. A connection to the server is opened and closed for each file. Is there any way to open the connection once and make the copy of the 10 (or more files) and then close it only at the end?

Comment: You might have better luck getting answers if you post your current script. Edit it into your question.

Comment: I can't put on the internet company code :-(. thanks anyway

Comment: If you are using `psftp.exe` to upload you can stack several `put` commands in the so called `batchfile` and use this with `-b` option to execute everything in one go.